# How to combine nth-child() rules into one?

Tags: html, css

I currently have this long rule

```
#content #wrapper table td:nth-child(3), 
#content #wrapper table td:nth-child(4), 
#content #wrapper table td:nth-child(5) {
     width: 30px;
}
```

is it possible to combine the nth-child to something shorter like `nth-child(3,4,5)` instead of 3 separate lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#content #wrapper table td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5) {
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much! Can you explain the last part please, im not sure how it works

Comment: @skyisred You might want to play a bit with this http://lea.verou.me/demos/nth.html

Answer (score 1):

Not directly based on your code, but this should give you an idea.

```
ul li:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+7){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a:nth-child(4),+:nth-child(5){color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
#content #wrapper table td:nth-child(n+3)
```

which will select all but the first 2.

FROM: http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score -3):

Not that I'm aware of I'm afraid.  If you're looking for less code in order to make it more maintainable, you could try something like SASS.